# Fetch JSON data with empty values

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to fetch data from this url - https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all which has some empty values. Basically I am trying to build a table with the list of dog breeds.

```js
$.getJSON("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all", function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(index, d) {
    $('#api-details tbody').append("<tr>" +
      "<td>" + d + "</td>" +
      "</tr>")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="api-details" class="table">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <th>List of Breeds</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is not returning the list of breeds but just sends an object to the HTML.

Comment: add  }); at the end of js you will miss it at the end.
Then it will return [object Object]

Comment: @Urocks that's the problem the OP is trying to solve

Answer (score 1):

Each breed is held within the keys of the `message` object in the response. As such you need to loop over those instead of the `data` object as a whole.

Also note that within each family of dog breed is the individual breed names, so you will need a second loop to output those as well. Try this:

```js
$.getJSON("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all", function(data) {
  var rows = '';
  Object.keys(data.message).forEach(function(family) {
    rows += '<tr><td>' + family + '</td></tr>';
    
    data.message[family].forEach(function(breed) {
      rows += '<tr><td> - ' + breed + '</td></tr>';
    })
  });
  $('#api-details tbody').append(rows);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="api-details" class="table">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <th>List of Breeds</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

That `json` data has two objects status and message, your data is stored in message

So you need to apply `each` for `data.message`

Please check below code :

```js
$.getJSON("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all", function (data) {
    $.each(data.message, function (index, d) {
        if (d != "") {
            $('#api-details tbody').append("<tr>" +
            "<td>" + d + "</td>" +
            "</tr>")
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="api-details" class="table">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr><th>List of Breeds</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This just returns the breed but not the family. Thanks for the help!